Pinescript labels are invisible
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    for i = 0 to 99
        label.new(x=bar_index - i,
                  y=na,
                  yloc=yloc.belowbar,
                  text="x",
                  style=label.style_none,
                  textcolor=color.blue)

Only the last 20 labels or so are visible.
I wanted to use the label, because it also has a tooltip option.
The documentation doesn't say anything about this.
Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

One must set the max_labels_count argument.
indicator("My Indicator", overlay=true, max_labels_count=500)

